# Crossword puzzle app

Tags: java, beginner, game, homework, io

I was hoping someone could give me any tips or advice on this program I wrote for my high school class. The point of the program is to create a workable crossword puzzle in the console. If it works well, I'm going to try and implement it with JavaFX.

It reads the crossword clues and other stuff in regards to the clues from a text file. Part of the assignment is to practice accessing files. I'm sure there's a better way to do that part.

I tried to comment the code so that it will be easy to read but the general idea is, the program starts with a 2D array of booleans that each say if the square is suppose to be black or white. When the puzzle object is created it is shown in the console with `*` representing black squares and clue numbers/periods representing the white squares. The user is given options to view all the clues and select one to answer, select a specific clue to answer, erase an answer, or check if the puzzle is correct.

This is the Main class

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main
{
    static Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        //region Grid
        boolean[][] grid = {{ true,     true,   true,   true,   true,   true,   false,  true,   true },
                            { true,     true,   true,   true,   true,   true,   false,  true,   true },
                            { true,     true,   false,  false,  false,  false,  false,  true,   true },
                            { true,     true,   true,   true,   true,   true,   false,  true,   true },
                            { true,     true,   true,   true,   true,   true,   false,  true,   true },
                            { true,     false,  false,  false,  false,  false,  false,  false,  true },
                            { true,     true,   true,   true,   false,  true,   false,  true,   true },
                            { true,     true,   true,   true,   false,  true,   true,   false,  true },
                            { false,    false,  false,  false,  false,  false,  false,  false,  true },
                            { true,     true,   true,   true,   false,  true,   true,   false,  true },
                            { true,     true,   true,   true,   true,   true,   true,   false,  true },
                            { true,     true,   true,   false,  false,  false,  false,  false,  false}
                            };
        //endregion
        Crossword cw = new Crossword(grid);

        while (true)
        {
            cw.printGrid();

            int option = DisplayOptions();
            System.out.println();

            int clue;

            // Main Game Player
            switch (option)
            {
                // Display all clues
                case 1 ->
                {
                    cw.printActiveClues();
                    System.out.println("Enter a clue to answer: ");
                    clue = userInput.nextInt();

                    SubmitClueAnswer(cw, clue);
                }
                // Display a specific clue
                case 2 ->
                {
                    System.out.println("Enter the clue you would like to see: ");
                    clue = userInput.nextInt();

                    cw.printSpecificClue(clue);
                    SubmitClueAnswer(cw, clue);
                }
                // Erase an answer
                case 3 ->
                {
                    System.out.println("Which answer would you like to erase? ");
                    clue = userInput.nextInt();
                    cw.getClue(clue).eraseFromPuzzle(cw.getPuzzle());
                }
                // Check if the puzzle is completed correctly
                case 4 ->
                {
                    if (cw.checkPuzzle())
                    {
                        System.out.println("Puzzle completed successfully!");
                        EndGame();
                    }else{
                        System.out.println("Puzzle completed unsuccessfully!");
                    }
                }
                // Exit the game
                case 5 -> EndGame();
                // Error message
                default -> System.out.println("Enter a number 1 - 5");
            }
        }
    }

    private static void SubmitClueAnswer(Crossword cw, int _clueNum)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter your guess: ");
        String guess = userInput.next();

        CheckAnswerSubmission(cw, _clueNum, guess);
    }
    private static void CheckAnswerSubmission(Crossword cw, int clue, String guess)
    {
        Clue attemptedClue = cw.getClue(clue - 1);
        String answer = attemptedClue.getAnswer();

        if (guess.equals(answer))
            attemptedClue.assignGuess(cw.getPuzzle(), guess, true);
        else
        {
            if (guess.length() == answer.length())
                attemptedClue.assignGuess(cw.getPuzzle(), guess, false);
            else
                System.out.println("Guess doesn't fit!");
        }
    }
    private static int DisplayOptions()
    {
        System.out.println("Select an option: ");
        System.out.println("1. Display all clues: ");
        System.out.println("2. Display a specific clue: ");
        System.out.println("3. Erase an answer: ");
        System.out.println("4. Submit Puzzle");
        System.out.println("5. Exit");

        return userInput.nextInt();
    }
    static void EndGame(){
        System.out.println("Have a nice day!");
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

This is the Crossword puzzle

```
public class Crossword
{
    private Square[][] puzzle;
    private ArrayList<Clue> allClues;

    public Crossword(boolean[][] blackSquares) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        buildClues();

        int clue = 0;
        puzzle = new Square[blackSquares.length][blackSquares[0].length];

        for (int r = 0; r < blackSquares.length; r++)
        {
            for (int c = 0; c < blackSquares[0].length; c++)
            {
                // Black square (*)
                if (blackSquares[r][c])
                    puzzle[r][c] = new Square(42);

                // White square with clue number (#)
                else if (toBeLabeled(r, c, blackSquares))
                    puzzle[r][c] = new Square(allClues.get(clue++).getClueNumber()+48);

                // White square (.)
                else
                    puzzle[r][c] = new Square(46);
            }
        }
    }

    //region Getters
    public Square[][] getPuzzle(){
        return puzzle;
    }
    public Clue getClue(int _idx) { return allClues.get(_idx); }
    //endregion

    //region Construction of puzzle
    public void printGrid()
    {
        for (Square[] squares : puzzle)
        {
            for (int c = 0; c < puzzle[0].length; c++)
                System.out.print(squares[c].getLetter() + "\t");

            System.out.println();
        }
    }
    public void buildClues() throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        allClues = FileHandling.readClues("src\\CrosswordPuzzle.txt");
    }
    private boolean toBeLabeled(int _r, int _c, boolean[][] _blackSquares)
    {
        // current square is black, don't label
        if (_blackSquares[_r][_c]) { return false; }

        // current square is white and on left edge or top edge
        if (_r == 0 || _c == 0) { return true; }

        // 1) current square is white and to the right of a black square
        // 2) current square is white and below a black square
        return (_r < 11 && (_blackSquares[_r - 1][_c] && !_blackSquares[_r + 1][_c])) ||
                (_c < 11 && (_blackSquares[_r][_c - 1] && !_blackSquares[_r][_c + 1]));
    }
    public void printCorrectPuzzle()
    {
        for (Clue c : allClues)
        {
            c.assignGuess(puzzle, c.getAnswer(), true);
        }
    }

    //endregion

    //region Gameplay
    public void printSpecificClue(int _idx)
    {
        Clue c = allClues.get(_idx - 1);
        System.out.println(c.getClue());
    }
    public void printActiveClues()
    {
        System.out.println("Horizontal:");
        for (Clue c : allClues)
        {
            if (!c.getIsGuessed() && c.getOrientation() == 'h')
            {
                System.out.print(c.getClueNumber() + ". ");
                System.out.println(c.getClue());
            }
        }
        System.out.println("\nVertical");
        for (Clue c : allClues)
        {
            if (!c.getIsGuessed() && c.getOrientation() == 'v')
            {
                System.out.print(c.getClueNumber() + ". ");
                System.out.println(c.getClue());
            }
        }
    }
    public boolean checkPuzzle()
    {
        boolean _isCorrect = true;

        for (Clue c : allClues)
        {
            if (!c.getIsCorrect())
            {
                _isCorrect = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        return _isCorrect;
    }

    //endregion

}
```

This class is for each clue

```
public class Clue
{
    private boolean isCorrect, isGuessed;
    private final char orientation;
    private final int row, col, clueNumber;
    private final String answer, clue;


    public Clue(int _row, int _col, char _orientation, int _cNum, String _answer, String _clue)
    {
        row = _row;
        col = _col;
        orientation = _orientation;
        clueNumber = _cNum;
        answer = _answer;
        clue = _clue;
    }

    //region Getters
    public String getAnswer(){
        return answer;
    }
    public String getClue() { return clue; }
    public char getOrientation() { return orientation; }
    public boolean getIsCorrect() { return isCorrect; }
    public boolean getIsGuessed() { return isGuessed; }
    public int getClueNumber() { return clueNumber; }
    //endregion

    public void assignGuess(Square[][] _board, String _guess, boolean _isCorrect)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < answer.length(); i++)
        {
            char c = _guess.charAt(i);

            if (orientation == 'h')
                _board[row][col+i].setLetter(Character.toUpperCase(c));
            else
                _board[row+i][col].setLetter(Character.toUpperCase(c));
        }

        isCorrect = _isCorrect;
        isGuessed = true;
    }
    public void eraseFromPuzzle(Square[][] _board)
    {
        char resetChar = '*';
        for (int i = 0; i < answer.length(); i++)
        {
            if (orientation == 'h')
                _board[row][col+i].setLetter(resetChar);
            else
                _board[row+i][col].setLetter(resetChar);
        }

        isCorrect = false;
        isGuessed = false;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return answer.toUpperCase();
    }

}
```

This class is for each individual square in the puzzle

```
public class Square
{
    private final int squareNumber;
    private char letter;

    public Square(int _num)
    {
        squareNumber = _num;
        letter = (char)_num;
    }

    public char getLetter() { return letter; }

    public void setLetter(char _letter)
    {
        letter = _letter;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return String.format("%02d", squareNumber);
    }
}
```

This is the class that just reads from the text file

```
public class FileHandling
{
    public final static String DELIMITER = ":";

    public static ArrayList<Clue> readClues(String _fileName) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        File file = new File(_fileName);
        ArrayList<Clue> allClues = new ArrayList<>();

        if (!file.exists())
        {
            System.out.printf("The file %s does not exist!\n", file);
            System.exit(0);
        }

        Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);

        while(inputFile.hasNext())
        {
            String currentLine = inputFile.nextLine();

            // Structure of the line being read:
            // (Row number : Column Number : Clue orientation : Clue number : Clue : Clue Answer)
            if (currentLine.contains(DELIMITER))
            {
                String[] splitLine = currentLine.split(DELIMITER);
                Clue c = new Clue(Integer.parseInt(splitLine[0]),Integer.parseInt(splitLine[1]),
                                    splitLine[2].charAt(0), Integer.parseInt(splitLine[3]), splitLine[4], splitLine[5]);
                allClues.add(c);
            }
        }

        inputFile.close();

        return allClues;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

There's a lot of improvement in both style and structure. I will concentrate on style only.

Use variable names that represent the purpose of the value. For example `grid` represents the data type, but not what it is used for. Better option would be

```
boolean[][] blockedSquares = {{ .....
```

Which brings us to the next naming issue: representing a positive trait (in this case "availability", a square where a letter can be placed) with a negative value (`false`) forces the code into using double negatives, which are hard for humans to follow. This makes your code difficult to read and maintain. So the best name for the variable is `openSquares` with the values flipped. The purpose of the puzzle is to fill the open squares so concentrate on those. The blocked squares are just filler.

Don't use colour to represent a trait in code. There is a fair bit of discussion around about why we tend to assign "black" colour to negative traits and "white" to  positive traits (for example blacklist/whitelist) and why it is problematic. Also, "black" doesn't really tell the reader that the square is unavailable, unless they have seen a crossword in a paper magazine. Colouring the squares should be left purely to the user interface implementation. Just use "open" and "blocked". They immediately tell the trait without forcing the reader to make a "mental lookup" into a color table. :)

A lot of things that make a good programmer is the ability to know the answer to question "will it be easy for the next person to understand this code?"

Since you have the correct answers in the file, hard coding the grid as a boolean array is completely redundant, cumbersome and error prone. You can create the array from the answers by setting the grid initially to "all blocked" and then opening the squares based on the starting location and the answer length. You don't even need to know the grid size in advance, because that too can be calculated from the answers.

In [Java naming conventions](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html), classes start with upper case letter and methods and variables start with lower case letter. The following is confusing as it looks like you are calling a constructor without the `new` keyword.

```
        int option = DisplayOptions();
```

You abruptly switch to using underscore prefixes in parameter names. Is that code you got from your instructor? Anyway,it does not follow Java naming conventions. If it's your code, it is better to be consistent with your naming conventions. Having multiple conventions in a single project makes reading it tedious and maintenance costly.

Don't use magic numbers and don't combine a field to contain two completely separate values. The status of the square should be represented as a two-way enumeration OPEN/BLOCKED and the number of the clue that starts from that square should be a separate field.

```
puzzle[r][c] = new Square(OPEN, clueNumber);
```

Don't mix user interface code into data models. The `Crossword` class is a data model for the puzzle but it also is responsible for user interface actions in the `printSpecificClue(int)` method. Especially if you plan on converting this to JavaFX later. The `printSpecificClue` method becomes unnecessary. It also violates the [single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle).

Be consistent in error handling. In the file reading code you check if the file exists and if it doesn't you print an error and `System.exit` out of the program. Later when you parse the file, you split the line and index it without checking if there is enough elements (throwing an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`) and convert the input without checking if they are actually numbers (throwing a `NumberFormatException`). So you should check the array length after splitting and catch the formatting exceptions and apply similar error handling as with the missing file. Maybe throw an `IllegalArgumentException` or an exception of your own.

```
String[] splitLine = currentLine.split(DELIMITER);
Clue c = new Clue(Integer.parseInt(splitLine[0]),
    Integer.parseInt(splitLine[1]),
    ...
```

Never use `System.exit` for handling errors. Calling System.exit here is like pulling the power cable from your computer because a file was missing. Just let the `FileNotFoundException` propagate to the caller, like you declare in the method's `throws` clause and let the user interface deal with it. When you move to JavaFX you probably would show an error dialog, which you now can't do because the application quit imediately.

You mentioned that you tried to comment the code to make it easier to read, but there are comments only in the main method and they're either redundant or could be made redundant by restructuring the code. For example the "//region Grid" comment is quite uninformative. Once you rename the variable, the comment becomes unnecessary. The comments in the switch-case become unnecessary if you refactor the code in them into methods, each of which handle the specific user action choice. For exameple:

```
switch (option) {
case 1 -> handleDisplayAllClues();  
case 2 -> handleDisplaySpecificClue();
...
```

The purpose of comments is to document **why** something is done. If the code is well written, then **what** the code does is usually obvious so it does not need to be repeated in the comments. Needing to put "//end region" like comments is often a sign that your code block is too long and it needs to be split into sub-methods.

Comment: If the "black", "white", "chartreuse"  issue is about using strings, that is a relevant issue. Strings are not type safe, are prone to misspelling, and sensitive to CaseING. enums are great because they have none of those problems

Comment: *"black" doesn't really tell the reader that the square is unavailable* -> yes it does. Black says "this square is *positively* not used." It is axiomatic in crossword puzzling. The New York Times Crossword Puzzle for example, uses black for unused squares.  It is wise for code to reflect the world it is simulating.

Comment: @radarbob Black does not tell the square is unavailable. It tells the reader to refer to a paper crossword puzzle. The paper crossword puzzle is what tells the user that the square is unavailable. It is always better to inclide information directly instead of forcing the reader to go through a reference. Regardless of how trivial the lookup is. All these little things add up to the congnitive load placed on the reader. And beyond that, the color black is user interface functionality. Defining the UI in the game backend violates the "separation of concerns" principle.

Comment: Well, splitting hairs during requirements analysis pays so:  Lay on, MacDuff!

Comment: @radarbob Sorry I don't know that reference. Can you elaborate on it?

Comment: [Shakespeare's MacBeth, Act 5, Scene 8, line 35](https://www.litcharts.com/shakescleare/shakespeare-translations/macbeth/act-5-scene-8)

Comment: And I ran across this:  [... the program has empathy with the mental model of the end user...](https://youtu.be/ZrBQmIDdls4?t=1045)

Comment: @radarbob Can you summarize it? Posting off-site links isn't a long term solution and I can't watch YouTube at the moment.

Comment: RE: "the program has empathy..." ; The money line is: *"in some sense the model [as in MVC] and the end user should be thinking about the same thing, that one is an extension of the other. This is the whole goal of object oriented programming."*.   ==> Thus, the crossword program should "understand" how the end user understands black squares in a crossword puzzle.